# Replace text with special characters using sed

Tags: shell, sed, jq, edit

I have a json string like this,

```
rssample='{ "Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"ResourceRecords":[{ "Value":""}], "Type": "TXT","NAME":"","TTL": 300}}]}'
```

I want to update the NAME and Value in it using the below variables..

```
name="testname"
newvalue="heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=us-east-1:sandbox-newtestowner,external-dns/resource=ingress/monitoring/prometheus-operator-alertmanager"
```

So I tried using sed,

```
   newrs=$(sed -E "s/"NAME":""/"NAME":"$name"/g" <<< "$rssample")
   newrs1=$(sed -E "s/"Value":""/"Value":"\$newvalue"/g" <<< "$newrs")
```

I am expecting below as output,

```
{ "Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"ResourceRecords":[{ "Value":"\"heritage=external-dns,external-dns/owner=us-east-1:sandbox-newtestowner,external-dns/resource=ingress/monitoring/prometheus-operator-alertmanager\""}], "Type": "TXT","NAME":"testname","TTL": 300}}]}
```

But I am empty Name.And getting error for value as,

```
sed: 1: "s/Value:/Value:"heritag ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'o'
```

My output is,
{ "Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"ResourceRecords":[{ "Value":""}], "Type": "TXT","NAME":"","TTL": 300}}]}

Please let me know how to fix this? is using sed good idea or jq?

Comment: `sed` is a terrible idea for dealing with recursive languages like JSON. Use `jq`. You'll find this sentiment reflected in tons of places around this site.

Comment: agree with above. Also, please try to understand the principal behind [mcve]. We only need to see the smallest amount of data that illustrates your problem. Having to scroll the screen only leads to errors. Use and accept that `jq` answer below! Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally safer, and therefore often better, to use a JSON-aware tool rather than `sed` when editing JSON. Using jq, one possibility would be:

```
jq --arg name "$name" --arg newvalue "$newvalue" '
  .Changes[0].ResourceRecordSet |= 
    (.NAME=$name
   | .ResourceRecords[0].Value = $newvalue)' <<< "$rssample"
```

### A free-form approach

```
jq --arg name "$name" --arg newvalue "$newvalue" '
  walk(if type == "object" 
       then if has("NAME") then .NAME=$name else . end 
            | if has("Value") then .Value = $newvalue else . end
        else . end)' <<< "$rssample"
```